# Recording and playback sound

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-due, shields, sound

I'm working in an art project, is some kind of loop between contact microphones and walkie talkies. I want to create some kind of noisy feedback.

I'm putting one walkie-talkie inside of a bottle, and in front of the speaker/microphone from the walkie I want to put another contact microphone attached to an Arduino, and record the sounds of the walkie talkie and played with some delay in some buzzer in front of another contact microphone attached to an amp with three speakers. To sum up, I have like 3 parts linked between them, the first one the walkie, the second one with an Arduino and the third one a simple mic whith an amp and three speakers.

Only the second part will be working with the Arduino and I want it to record sound and play it simultaneously with some delay.
I worked with a friend with some servo motors and music shields and I've been doing some research. I found 3 very interesting projects one is this, that it's practically what I want to do [Space Replay](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/674/how-does-the-space-replay-record-audio)but there's so little information about it, and the other two are [Arduino Audio Input](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Audio-Input/) and [Arduino Audio Output](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Audio-Output/)
So, my questions are:

- If I use a music shield I don't need a DAC or/and an amp? or only an amp if my speakers are too loud?
- In the project Space Replay they only use [this music shield](https://www.adafruit.com/product/94) so with only one music shield I can record and play music simultaneously? or I need two music shields?
- That Adafruit Wave Shield is only for Arduino uno, but it will be better or easier to work with DUE or Arduino Mega and another music shields or making my own circuits like in the instructables Arduino Audio Input and Output?

I don't care too much about the quality of the audio, as I said the purpose is make some noise. The only thing is I want to create some kind of echo, or some kind of cannon, between the first sound of the walkie and the others pick up sounds.

Any other comment or advice will be much appreciated and welcomed.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try using [this](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1788) shield from Adafruit. I believe it can record and play audio, and they have versions with and without amps.

I do not know about near-simultaneous playback, so read up a bit before buying.

Comment: @user173724 Hello, thank you for the answer. I found an example project with the adafruit waveshield, which is realtime voice changer more information [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/wave-shield-voice-changer/), also  in the waveRP library includes a folder with how to connect a mic to the wave shield, so I'm working with the wave shield but I'll take a look to the Music Maker shield.